Gnome 46 on debian 13 doesn't have new UI features
Summary:
I am Using Debian 13 testing with Gnome 46, the way i installed it was the debian-recomended way. Everything worked perfectly but I didn't get the new workspace indicator, instead, I got the old "activities" button.
Details:
The way i installed debian was using the netinstaller from the main download link to install debian 12 stable with gnome 43, then replace every "bookworm" in etc/apt/source.list with "testing".
Then I do sudo apt update & sudo apt full-upgrade & sudo apt dist-upgrade, then reboot.
I checked the gnome version from the settings app, and it says version 46. I know that this is a small problem, but I still want to know what i did wrong, is it me, or is the gnome package in the debian repo modified.

Debian is still using some old version on gnome 46 until they insure it's stable, so you need some time to get the latest version with full features(like me , I'm using gnome 46 with nautilus 45.2 :) )

@HayderCtee for debian testing?
